# GetObjectAsync() not working on VS2019 version 16.9.3 - NET 5 app using AWSSDK.S3 version 3.7.0.6

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-s3, .net-5

- VS2019 version: 16.9.3
- Target Framework: .NET 5
- Nuget Pkg: AWSSDK.S3 version 3.7.0.6

I have a simple block of code that has always worked, but has now suddenly stopped working. I now get the error: "The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid", when executing the AWS S3 Client API Method: GetObjectAsync(BucketName, Key).

Here is one thing that happened that *may* be relevant I just upgraded to Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.9.3.

I am running on .NET 5 and using the AWSSDK.S3 version 3.7.0.6 nuget pkg.

Any help appreciated!

Here is sample code that now blows up as described:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

using (var client = new AmazonS3Client("AccessKey",
                       "SecretAccessKey",
                       "MyRegion"))
{
    try
    {
        string BucketName = "my-files";
        string Key = "my.pdf";
        response = await client.GetObjectAsync(BucketName, Key);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Error Here! - "The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid"
          throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solved it!***

The specific change that has been introduced somewhere is that the "Region" parameter in

```
new AmazonS3Client()
```

can no longer be a string. It must be a RegionEndpoint Enum. (Even though the API allows a string!)

So this works:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(key, secret, RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1)
```

I have a work-around, but this is a bug.

Previously, I could use "eu-central-1" or "us-east-1", which is a lot more convenient because I can read it directly from appsettings.json.

It could be that the accepted string format has changed for this parameter (but why!)